# Cross referencing decorators

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-decorators, cross-reference

The python domain in sphinx has `.. py:decorator::` to document decorators, but how to cross reference a decorator?

For functions (documented with `.. py:function::`) there is `:py:func:`. What is the equivalent for decorators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in sphinx's documentation:

> There is no py:deco role to link to a decorator that is marked up with this directive; rather, use the py:func role.
>   http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#directive-py:decorator

The official solution is to use `:py:func:`. It works too. Unfoutunately sphinx adds brackets after the decorator name.

```
text py:func:`mydecorator` text
```

becomes in the output:

```
text mydecorator() text
```

The brakets can be disabled globally, but I quite like them when referencing real functions.

Comment: You can change link text in the reference with `:func:\`@mydecorator()<mydecorator>\``. You can omit parentheses if you don't want them, e.g. decorator doesn't has args.